How to display a dynamic List of JButtons in a JPanel
I have a panel that has a button above it to add a new category to a list and then I want to display that list below that button.
public class ConfigCategories extends JPanel {
public final List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();

public ConfigCategories() {
    super();
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    setOpaque(false);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(L10N.t("elementgui.config.categories.title")));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width, 50));

    JButton addCategory = new JButton("Add New Category");
    addCategory.setOpaque(false);
    addCategory.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, addCategory.getPreferredSize().height));
    addCategory.setBackground(Theme.current().getBackgroundColor());
    addCategory.setForeground(Theme.current().getForegroundColor());
    addCategory.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 2, 0));
    ComponentUtils.deriveFont(addCategory, 11);
    addCategory.addActionListener(e -> {
        new NewCategoryDialog(this);
    });

    add(addCategory);
}

public void update() {
    for (String name: categories) {
        JButton b = new JButton(name);
        b.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, b.getPreferredSize().height));
        b.setBackground(Theme.current().getBackgroundColor());
        b.setForeground(Theme.current().getForegroundColor());
        b.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        add(b);
    }
    updateUI();
}
}

public class NewCategoryDialog extends JDialog {
private final VTextField name = new VTextField(20);
public NewCategoryDialog(ConfigCategories configCategories) {
    super(w, L10N.t("dialog.config.new_category"), true);

    setSize(580, 195);
    setLocationRelativeTo(w);

    add(PanelUtils.westAndEastElement(L10N.label("Name:"), name));

    JButton ok = new JButton(UIManager.getString("OptionPane.okButtonText"));
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(ok);

    JButton cancel = new JButton(UIManager.getString("OptionPane.cancelButtonText"));
    cancel.addActionListener(e -> setVisible(false));

    ok.addActionListener(e -> {
        setVisible(false);
        configCategories.categories.add(name.getText());
        configCategories.update();
    });

    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, PanelUtils.join(ok, cancel));

    setVisible(true);
}
}

This code works well, But I want to know how can I delete all the buttons added to the panel except the first button (button to add category)?
Because when I add the second, third, etc. button, the previous buttons are added again
Adding first button:

Adding second button:


There should be no need to delete previously added buttons. Your logic should be to prompt the user for the category and then to 1) add the button to frame and 2) add the category to the category list. That is don't try to recreate all the buttons from the category list each time. Also, don't use the updateUI() method. That is only invoked when you do a Look and Feel change. When adding (or removing) components from a visible frame you should use revalidate() and repaint() on the panel that changes.
